# How to add multiple data series to a scatterplot and how to format numbers to appear in standard form on y axis

Tags: r

My data set:

```
    structure(list(Site = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Average.worm.weight..g. = c(0.1934, 
    0.249, 0.263, 0.262, 0.4186, 0.204, 0.311, 0.481, 0.326, 0.657, 
    0.347, 0.311, 0.239, 0.4156, 0.31, 0.3136, 0.4033, 0.302, 0.277
    ), Average.total.immune.cell.count = structure(c(8L, 16L, 11L, 
    12L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 15L, 4L, 3L, 17L, 13L, 18L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
    14L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "168750", "18650000", "200,000", "21,600,000", 
    "226666.6", "22683333.33", "2533333.33", "283333.333", "291666.6", 
    "335833.3", "435800", "474816666.7", "500000", "6450000", "729166.667", 
    "7433333.3", "9916667"), class = "factor"), Average.eleocyte.number =          structure(c(2L, 
    5L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 15L, 8L, 12L, 3L, 
    11L, 13L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "1266666.67", "153333.3", "168740", 
    "17", "200,000", "2266666.667", "22683333.33", "23116666.67", 
    "264000", "283333.333", "442", "500000", "7.3", "9916667"), class = "factor")),     .Names = c("Site", 
    "Average.worm.weight..g.", "Average.total.immune.cell.count", 
    "Average.eleocyte.number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -19L))
```

This is my R script so far:

Plotting multiple data series on a graph

```
    y1<-dframe1$"Average.total.immune.cell.count"    
    y2<-dframe1$"Average.eleocyte.number"    
    x<-dframe1$"Average.worm.weight..g."
    plot.default(y1~x,type="p" )
    points(y2~x)
```

I am trying to add to y series to the same scatterplot and I am struggling to do so, I want to have different symbols for the points so as to tell apart the two different data series. Also I would like the axes to meet on the bottom left hand side and would appreciate being informed as to how I can do that? I would also like the y axis to be in standard form, but do not know how to get R to do that.

Best regards.
K.

Comment: Because when I copied and pasted it I had trouble formatting it as it is very long.

Comment: highlight the code and use the `{}` tag. or just put it in any old way, and someone else can edit it for you

Comment: I have done that now.

Comment: what do you mean you want the axes to meet on the bottom left hand side? doesn't it do that already? And what do you mean by the y-axis standard form?

Comment: well there is a gap between the x and the y axis when I submit it via R. They do not meet at the origin.I have data that is in the thousands and millions, and I want R to present it as 10^3 for example not just as two digit values because then it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is an object lesson is getting your data in the correct format to begin with. Your numbers have commas, which R does not like. Hence the numbers get converted to character and imported as factors (which your `structure(...)` clearly shows. You need to fix that, or better yet get rid of the commas prior to exporting.

Something like this will work

```
colnames(dframe) <- c("Site","x","y1","y2")
dframe$y1 <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",","",dframe$y1,fixed=TRUE)))
dframe$y2 <- as.numeric(as.character(gsub(",","",dframe$y2,fixed=TRUE)))
plot(y1~x,dframe, col="red", pch=20)
points(y2~x,dframe, col="blue", pch=20)
```

But there are additional problems. One of the numbers (in row 12) is a factor of 10 larger than all the others, so the plot above is not very informative. It's hard to know if this is a data input error, or a genuine outlier in your data.

**EDIT**: Response to OP's comment

```
dframe <- dframe[-12,]               # remove row 12
dframe <- dframe[order(dframe$x),]   # order by increasing x
plot(y1~x,dframe, col="red", pch=20, type="b")
points(y2~x,dframe, col="blue", pch=20, type="b")
legend("topleft",legend=c("y1","y2"),col=c("red","blue"),pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful. I have deleted that data point. The graph now looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/b0DT4l6.jpg I was wondering how I could add a legend to it? Also, would it be possible in R to link the points with a line? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, you have answered my question very well.